# How can I debug IPython display methods?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I'm writing `_repr_latex_`, `_repr_html_`, `__repr__` methods.

The problem that I'm facing is that I want to debug the call chain, because I bumped in to a situation like this.

```py
class A:
    def _get_text(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

    def _repr_html_(self):
        text = self._get_text()
        return f"<b>{text}</b>"

class B(A):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} >"

class C(B):
    def _get_text(self):
        return "I'm C, an equivalent data structure with different meaning."
```

And whenever I try to display by stating an object `c = C` at the end of a code block, it displays the `__repr__` not the `_repr_html_`, corresponding to the class `C`.

If anyone knows what is a common debugging process for this situation?

Comment: To make the `_repr_html_` method the default representation for your class, you can define the `__repr__` method to call the `_repr_html_` method. Could this help you? If not please add more details

Comment: Doing that would make `__repr__` a raw HTML string in a regular terminal.

Also, when displaying in a notebook, it will also just show a raw HTML string.

Comment: Maybe you can delete the `__repr__` method from the class with the `del` keyword so that the notebook is forced to call `_repr_html_`

Comment: I posted my own answer, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining all the methods, mentioned, I realized that there was an exception occurring in one of the methods, forcing a *fallback* to `__repr__`.

The conclusion is to make sure that the `_repr_{type}_` doesn't raise exceptions.

Comment: Fascinating stuff, I had no idea about this, +1